# How to monitor my data limit on a mobile broadband connection?

Tags: mobile-broadband, monitoring

I recently got a 3G dongle with a data plan of 200MB per month and I would like to know when I reach that limit. Are there any programs (preferably an indicator) which let my monitor my monthly usage?

Mobile Partner 23 has this functionality but is not available for Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NETWORK TRAFFIC MONITOR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netramon/).
There is [Datafox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/datafox/?src=search), an addon for Firefox to monitor traffic on firefox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although NTM is ugly, it does exactly what I asked for. Datafox, is only for 2 Indian providers so it is not that useful for me ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is a package for this called [`modem-manager-gui`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/modem-manager-gui/):

[image: modem-manager-gui screenshot]

Canonical's repositories currently contain recent versions for Ubuntu Trusty and newer. For Precise (and earlier) use this PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxonly/modem+manager+gui 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install modem-manager-gui
```

See the [official site](http://linuxonly.ru/cms/page.php?7).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in Raring this package is not available, so I installed it via PPA. The program does implement data limits but only for one session. So you cannot monitor your total data usage for a month (maybe in a later version you can).