# Checking data usage in a mobile broadband connection in ubuntu

Tags: mobile-broadband

I use a huawei dongle to access the Internet and since mobile partner doesn't support Ubuntu is there a way to check the data usage? any app maybe?

Comment: Install modem-manager-gui. It has same function as mobile partner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to monitor my data limit on a mobile broadband connection?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/328140/how-to-monitor-my-data-limit-on-a-mobile-broadband-connection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it in every System Monitor (or Task Manager) like in this one from Gnome:

[image: Gnome System Monitor screenshot]

Comment: Thats a good thing... hidden behind and I was searching for here and there... Thank you buddy...

Answer (score 6):

`vnstat` is probably the best way to do this. It can be installed using the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install vnstat
```

If you don't want to keep checking the data usage status every time then use:

```
watch -n 5 --differences vnstat -d ppp0
```

It would display the status every 5 seconds in the open terminal with the differences that occur in the values. `-d` is used to display the status of each day and `eth0` is the Ethernet used for internet connection (`wlan0` may be used for WiFi).

#### Sample output:

```
 ppp0  /  daily
         day         rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
      02/07/15     99.11 MiB |   11.10 MiB |  110.21 MiB |   10.45 kbit/s
      02/08/15     25.09 MiB |    3.75 MiB |   28.84 MiB |    5.37 kbit/s
     ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
     estimated        49 MiB |       5 MiB |      54 MiB |
```

**NOTE:** Type `ifconfig` in Terminal and see the output. The `ppp` thing followed by a number(could be `ppp0`) is your dongle. Use it with `vnstat` as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between a GTK tool, NTM:

http://netramon.sourceforge.net/eng/index.html

And a more advanced command line tool, vnStat:

http://humdi.net/vnstat/