# Network Usage Monitor

Tags: 16.04, mobile-broadband, system-monitor, network-monitoring

Is there any working app to monitor Daily, Weekly , Monthly data usage via wifi/Ethernet. I do have limited data usage plans.

System monitor is not of my taste, it just tell me data usage of current session and high on CPU and RAM also.

It must have some provision to block network traffic after a set limit.

Earlier there was a tool named download-monitor, now it is not available in software center. I also tried some old repository, they are also not available.

It is a must have utility for me. I connect using mobile hotspot for connecting to internet. I know i can set limit in mobile but for some reason, it is not working in case of wireless tethering, which caused me lot of charges.

Please suggest a good working GUI app for ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 Bit.

thanks

Comment: Most mobile broadband providers have a web page where you can see your current usage, or a special number you can send a text message to to retrieve usage info, have you investigated this ? This would be a lot more accurate than a software based solution. That said, have you looked at [How to monitor my data limit on a mobile broadband connection?](http://askubuntu.com/q/328140)

Comment: Have you tried `dstat`?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/971154/16-04-character-monitor-equivalent-of-gui-system-monitor

Answer (score 4):

You can install `vnstat`. It is a CLI tool which doesn't have a GUI pre-installed. 
[image]

You can try adding following PHP frontend onto the vnstat to have a proper GUI. http://www.sqweek.com/sqweek/?p=1
[image]

You may also try free Webmin app, it is a web based server management software. You can do more than just monitoring the network but especially for network you can monitor specific interface and filter them by date/hour/minutes. 
http://www.webmin.com/