# 16.04 Character Monitor equivalent of GUI System-Monitor

Tags: command-line, ssh, software-recommendation, system-monitor

At the console in the GUI it is easy to pull up the System monitor to see CPU load, Memory usage, and Network utilization.

[image]

As I mention in this answer:

[System Monitor doesn't accurately show memory usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787642/system-monitor-doesnt-accurately-show-memory-usage/971157#971157)

I use the `htop` command sometimes, but am more interested in seeing a running history trend just like System-monitor instead of instantaneous values like `htop` shows

So is there a character terminal equivalent that can show trends and also run over `ssh` connections?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System monitor in console mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191750/system-monitor-in-console-mode)

Comment: Also, plenty of CLI commands in https://askubuntu.com/questions/293426/system-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu

Comment: Edited to explain why this is not a duplicate.  Also provided a lot of detail about `htop` in the answer I referenced that are missing from the duplicate that was flagged.

Comment: :shrug: Since the entire point of this question is to share your knowledge, I don't see why you can't simply post this answer on the dupe instead of going through all this bother to differentiate this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `dstat`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dstat
```

then run it by simply entering

```
dstat
```

to get this default output which updates every second and provides column headers with every screenful:

[image]

---

`dstat` is very versatile.  Here is an article that explains the command line switches and shows some of the advanced options:

[5+ “dstat” Command Usage Examples in Linux](http://www.sanfoundry.com/5-dstat-command-usage-examples-in-linux/)

Comment: Actually, after writing this post I discovered that it works really well to use Xming with PuTTY to get an X11 terminal over `ssh` - not on point of the question, but if I had discovered this first the question would not have been necessary:  http://www.geo.mtu.edu/geoschem/docs/putty_install.html